# matplotlib PdfPages compounding images

Tags: python, matplotlib, pdf-generation

I am iterating through a large list of strings and making a PDF file for each of them using matplotlib's PdfPages backend. When I just do one at a time (instead of iterating through all the strings), it works great. However, when I iterate, I get tons of extra lines that don't correspond to anything in my legend, and it's really confusing me. I suspect it's some issue with an object hanging around after I need it. Here's the pseudo-code for what I'm writing:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

def main():
    stringList = import(stringList) #Not an actual function, this is just where I get my list
    for s in stringList:
        pp = PdfPages(s+'.pdf')
        plotData(s, pp)
        pp.close()

def plotData(s, pp):
    dataList1, dataList2 = importData(s) #Again, not an actual function, just getting my data

    #Make first figure
    firstFig = plt.figure("first")
    firstax = firstFig.add_subplot(111)
    firstFig.suptitle("First")
    xaxis = [x for x in range(len(dataList1))]
    firstax.plot(xaxis, dataList2, label='local max')
    tempax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.02, 1., .102), loc=3,
       ncol=2, mode="expand", borderaxespad=0.)
    pp.savefig()

    #Make second figure
    #Exactly the same thing....

    #Make third figure
    #Exactly the same thing...
```

Again, I think it has something do with how I'm using these objects, and the documentation is pretty dry (I promise I've been all over it all day), but if someone knows what's going on here, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: try not putting an argument in `plt.figure()`.  Each pass through the loop you are re-using the _same_ figure.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks. Let's get an official answer up so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By specifying a string as the argument to `plt.figure()` you are re-using the same figures
each time through the loop.  The simplest way to deal with this is to simply not specify the string and use

```
fig = plt.figure()
```

It would also be good to put a

```
plt.close('all')
```

at the bottom of each loop to release all of the references pyplot has to the figure object.